# C library that converts integers to string and vice-versa

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, library, integer

I've created this little library to help ease myself (and for others, hopefully) with the pain of having to convert integers to string and vice-versa. It's written in C, and for maximum portability I decided to try and stick to C89 (no booleans yet by that time I believe). I'd like to ask you to give some of your comments and your recommendations, especially on the performance side.

Please note that when I was writing this code, my focus was on readability, self-documenting code and safety. Please also note that my naming convention varies very much from the C naming conventions that I'm sure a lot of you are used to seeing; e.g. abbreviated words instead of the complete words like "recv" for "receive", "u" for "unsigned", etc so if I confuse you with my naming convention then I hope you understand that readability was one of my primary concerns.

For some of the code which I thought some people might find unclear, I've added some comments in hopes of clearing up any confusion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*CONSTANTS*/

    /* ERROR MESSAGES */
    const char *invalidInputError = "convert.c: Unable to convert the input string into a valid number. Offending character has an ASCII value of %d. Valid ASCII values are from 48 to 57 (inclusive) and the null terminator '\0' at the end of the input string.";
    const char *outOfBoundariesError = "convert.c: Value was outside of boundaries. Minimum value is 0 and maximum value is  4,294,967,295. Value was %ul";

    /* BOUNDARIES */
    #define CONVERT_UNSIGNED_INT_MAX 4294967295
    #define CONVERT_SIGNED_INT_MIN -2147483648
    #define CONVERT_SIGNED_INT_MAX  2147483647
    #define CONVERT_UNSIGNED_MIN 0
    #define CONVERT_ASCII_ZERO 48
    #define CONVERT_ASCII_NINE 57

unsigned int FromStringToUnsignedInteger(char inputString[])
{
    unsigned long long boundariesChecker;
    unsigned int returnResult; returnResult = 0;
    int counter; counter = 0;
    // if the ASCII value is not between 48 and 57 inclusive, that's an error, except for '\0', which is the null terminator for C.
    while (inputString[counter] != '\0')
    {
        // check that the input is valid.
        if (inputString[counter] >= CONVERT_ASCII_ZERO && inputString[counter] <= CONVERT_ASCII_NINE)
        {
            // 48 is ASCII for 0, 49 for 1, 50 for 2, ..., 57 for 9.
            returnResult = (returnResult * 10) + (inputString[counter] - 48);
            boundariesChecker = returnResult;
            // check for overflow by getting the max of an unsigned integer (4,294,967,295)
            if (boundariesChecker > CONVERT_UNSIGNED_INT_MAX || boundariesChecker < CONVERT_UNSIGNED_MIN)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, outOfBoundariesError, returnResult);
                return 0;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, invalidInputError, inputString[counter]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return returnResult;
}

int FromStringToInteger(char inputString[])
{
    long long boundariesChecker;
    int returnResult; returnResult = 0;
    int counter;
    int isNegative = 0;
    // if it's a negative number skip the minus sign and set the flag.
    if (inputString[0] == '-')
    {
        counter = 1;
        isNegative = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = 0;
        isNegative = 0;
    }
    // if the ASCII value is not between 48 and 57 inclusive, that's an error, except for '\0', which is the null terminator for C.
    while (inputString[counter] != '\0')
    {
        // check that the input is valid.
        if (inputString[counter] >= CONVERT_ASCII_ZERO && inputString[counter] <= CONVERT_ASCII_NINE)
        {
            // 48 is ASCII for 0, 49 for 1, 50 for 2, ..., 57 for 9.
            returnResult = (returnResult * 10) + (inputString[counter] - 48);
            boundariesChecker = returnResult;
            // check for overflow by getting the max of an unsigned integer (4,294,967,295)
            if (boundariesChecker > CONVERT_SIGNED_INT_MAX || boundariesChecker < CONVERT_SIGNED_INT_MIN)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, outOfBoundariesError, returnResult);
                return 0;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, invalidInputError, inputString[counter]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if (isNegative)
    {
        returnResult = returnResult * -1;
    }
    return returnResult;
}

char *FromUnsignedIntegerToString(unsigned int inputUnsignedInt) {
    // check for out of range
    if (inputUnsignedInt > CONVERT_UNSIGNED_INT_MAX || inputUnsignedInt < CONVERT_UNSIGNED_MIN)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, outOfBoundariesError, inputUnsignedInt);
        return NULL;
    }
    // 10 is the multiplier because there's only 10 chars in the max value of an unsigned int.
    char *convertedInputUnsignedInt = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(convertedInputUnsignedInt, "%u", inputUnsignedInt);
    return convertedInputUnsignedInt;
}

char *FromIntegerToString(int inputInt) {
    // check for out of range
    if (inputInt > CONVERT_SIGNED_INT_MAX || inputInt < CONVERT_SIGNED_INT_MIN)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, outOfBoundariesError, inputInt);
        return NULL;
    }
    // 11 is the multiplier because there's only 11 chars in the max value of an unsigned int, including the negative sign.
    char *convertedInputUnsignedInt = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(convertedInputUnsignedInt, "%d", inputInt);
    return convertedInputUnsignedInt;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have constants indented to right ?

Comment: @JaDogg I got spoiled by Visual Studio indenting things for me to the right. It's a pet peeve. :)

Comment: btw Checkout code review chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Comment: why not use `sprintf()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the interface:

You have no header for clients to include which defines the API clients are expected to use.

As you print a message and then return a value cannot be determined to be invalid, the client code has no chance of sensibly dealing with an overflow itself, and you're polluting stderr. They might want to print something in French.

It'd be better to return a value and a status, so the client code can deal with the error as it sees fit (and you should have a different state for overflow and invalid string).

The `inputString`s should be `char const *` - you don't need to alter them, and this gives both you and the client confidence that you don't.

You don't flag to the client that they're meant to free the string on exit. You must do that, or alternatively ask for a buffer to be supplied and do your sprintf into that.

Now to the implementation:

Use `<limits.h>` to work out the min/max possible values for integer types.

Initialisation of `isNegative` is potentially done twice, and isn't particularly readable. Perhaps write it like this:

```
int counter = 0;
int isNegative = 0;
if (inputString[0] == '-')
{
    isNegative = !isNegative;
    ++counter;
}
```

Declare boundariesChecker in the block in which it is used.

`int fred; fred = 0` reads strangely.  What's wrong with `int fred = 0;`?

`CONVERT_ASCII_ZERO` should be `'0'` (and similarly for the NINE). Then you can drop the ASCII tag, as this'd work fine on EBCDIC machines.

`returnResult = -returnResult` would work fine and be probably more readable.

You don't check for `malloc` returning `NULL`.

Lastly, `long long` isn't available in C89 except as an extension, so you can't use it for overflow checking.

Comment: thanks. Actually I do have a header file, but I didn't include it here. Will take note of what you said.

For the int fred; fred = 0; part, you can blame that on CLion, it likes to suggest code like that. Will take note of that as well.

Comment: If you have a header file you should include it in the .c file as well, so I assumed you didn't

Comment: "CONVERT_ASCII_ZERO should be '0' ...  drop the ASCII tag, ...  fine on EBCDIC machines." changes the program's goal.  In general I agree that this is _typically_ what should happen.  The coding character set and the user IO character set are often the same.  But if the goal was to translate ASCII input, even if the source code was non-ASCII (e.g. EBCDIC), then OP's approach is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your code. I'll just look at the first function,
`FromStringToUnsignedInteger`

- the function name is verbose. `str_to_uint` would suffice.
- the prototype should not print errors but instead should return the
  conversion status and the result, so this would be better:

  ```
  int str_to_uint(const char *s, unsigned int *n);
  ```
- the limits should be from limits.h (UINT_MAX, INT_MAX etc)
- accumulating the result in an `int` means you cannot handle the
  full range of UINT_MAX
- and because you accumulate in an `int`, by the time you assign the
  intermediate result to `boundariesChecker`, any overflow has already
  happened and gone.  You need to accumulate in something bigger than
  `unsigned int` and use that directly for the bound check.
- checking for the result being less than 0 is unnecessary for an unsigned.
  Accumulate using an unsigned type.
- use `isdigit()` frm ctype.h to check for a number
- use '0' instead of '48'
- your comments are noisy (i.e. excessive and unhelpful)
- your variable names are unnecessarily long.

Here's an example of how it might be written:

```
errno_t str_to_uint(const char *s, unsigned int *n)
{
    unsigned long long res = 0;

    for (; *s; ++s) {
        if (!isdigit(*s)) {
            return EINVAL;
        }
        res = (res * 10) + (unsigned long long) (*s - '0');
        if (res > UINT_MAX) {
            return ERANGE;
        }
    }
    *n = (unsigned int) res;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I've said, my naming convention varies very much from the C naming conventions; it's verbose and loud, but that is because I designed it that way.

What about on code efficiency? Have any suggestions to make it faster?

Comment: Verbose/loud is a design option - but one that I think makes the code less readable.  You may disagree, that's ok. On efficiency, it doesn't hurt to be efficient if it comes at no cost, but efficiency is really a non-issue with this code *unless* you are using the functions *very* often and it causes a measurable bottleneck. Better to be clear and understandable.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I'm currently updating the entire code base from all the feedback I had. I'll post it here when I'm done for the benefit of all.

Comment: @pacoalphonso Don't update the question with new code, Instead post a followup question.

Comment: 1) `(unsigned long long) (*s - '0')` could be simplified to `*s - '0';`. 2) This approach depends on `UINT_MAX < ULLONG_MAX`: reasonable, but not specified in C.

Answer (score 1):

Taking on `FromStringToInteger()` and `FromIntegerToString()`.

First, using a "bigger" integer type is not always available and is **not needed**.  `long long` *may* have the same range as `int`, so why use `long long`.  Further, what if code was attempting to convert the maximum width integer type?  Best to use a solution that works within the given type.

```
long long boundariesChecker;  // not needed
int returnResult;
```

OP's code attempts to test for overflow *after* it happened.  Per C spec, that is UB and it is too late.

Second, negation is a problem when trying to convert a string to `INT_MIN`.  Negating `INT_MIN` is UB when `INT_MIN` < `-INT_MAX`.

To solve this, test for overflow *before* multiplication and **use the negative side of `int`**.  Need a basic re-write of code.

```
int FromStringToInteger(const char inputString[]) { // Add `const`
  int returnResult = 0;
  size_t counter = 0;  // should use `size_t` here
  int overflow = 0;  // could use `bool` here

  char sign = inputString[0]; 
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') { // Look for + sign too
    counter++;
  }

  while (inputString[counter] != '\0') {
    int digit = inputString[counter++];
    if (digit < CONVERT_ASCII_ZERO || digit > CONVERT_ASCII_NINE) {
      fprintf(stderr, invalidInputError, digit);
      return 0;
    }

    digit -= CONVERT_ASCII_ZERO;
    // Test if overflow is about to occur...
    if ((returnResult <= INT_MIN / 10) && 
        ((returnResult < INT_MIN / 10) || (-digit < INT_MIN % 10))) {
      returnResult = INT_MIN;
      overflow = 1;
      break;
    }

    returnResult = returnResult * 10 - digit;  // note use of -
  }

  if (sign != '-') {
    if (returnResult < -INT_MAX) {
      returnResult = INT_MAX;
      overflow = 1;
    } else {
      returnResult = -returnResult;
    }
  }

  if (overflow) {
    // At this point, returnResult is INT_MAX or INT_MIN 
    fprintf(stderr, outOfBoundariesError, returnResult);
    return returnResult;  // or drop through
  }

  return returnResult;
}
```

---

`FromIntegerToString()`

With all the macros for portability, using `11` is wrong.

Better to scale the buffer based of `INT_MIN` or `sizeof(int)` and test for OOM.
See [ansi-c-maximum-number-of-characters-printing-a-decimal-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536207/ansi-c-maximum-number-of-characters-printing-a-decimal-int/26068041#26068041)

`sizeof(char)` is *always* 1.  Little point in using it here.  If code might change from `char` to `wchar_t`, then better to use `malloc(n * sizeof *convertedInputUnsignedInt);`

```
// char *convertedInputUnsignedInt = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));

#define INT_STR_SIZE(type) (10*sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT/33 + 3)

char *convertedInputUnsignedInt = malloc(INT_STR_SIZE(int));
if (convertedInputUnsignedInt == NULL) {
  Handle_OOM();
}
```

Comment: @pacoalphonso UB: Undefined behavior.  Code has done something it should not do.  Code should _not_ be expected to behave in any fashion from now on.  You are lucky if you get a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally updated the functions and have come up with these:

Header:

```
#ifndef CONVERT_H
#define CONVERT_H

/* Structs */

typedef struct ToIntegerResult {char ErrorStatus; int IntegerResult;} ToIntegerResult;
typedef struct ToUnsignedIntegerResult {char ErrorStatus; unsigned int UnsignedIntegerResult;} ToUnsignedIntegerResult;

/* Prototypes */
ToUnsignedIntegerResult FromStringToUnsignedInteger(const char inputString[]);
void FromUnsignedIntegerToString(unsigned int inputUnsignedInt, char buffer[]);
ToIntegerResult FromStringToInteger(const char inputString[]);
void FromIntegerToString(char buffer[], int inputInt);





#endif /*CONVERT_H*/
```

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "convert.h"

/*CONSTANTS*/

#define CONVERT_ZERO '0'
#define CONVERT_NINE '9'

ToUnsignedIntegerResult FromStringToUnsignedInteger(const char inputString[])
{

    ToUnsignedIntegerResult returnResult;
    char wasReturnResultSet = 0;
    returnResult.ErrorStatus = 0;
    returnResult.UnsignedIntegerResult = 0;
    size_t counter = 0;
    while (inputString[counter] != '\0') {
        unsigned int digit = inputString[counter++];
        if (digit < CONVERT_ZERO || digit > CONVERT_NINE)
        {
            returnResult.ErrorStatus = -1; // invalid input
            return returnResult;
        }
        digit -= CONVERT_ZERO;

        // check for overflow
        if (wasReturnResultSet != 0 && (returnResult.UnsignedIntegerResult * 10 + digit) < returnResult.UnsignedIntegerResult)
        {
            // detected overflow
            returnResult.ErrorStatus = 1;
            return returnResult;
        }

        // set it so that the above check would work
        wasReturnResultSet = 1;

        returnResult.UnsignedIntegerResult = returnResult.UnsignedIntegerResult * 10 + digit;
    }

    return returnResult;
}

ToIntegerResult FromStringToInteger(const char inputString[])
{
    ToIntegerResult returnResult;
    returnResult.ErrorStatus = 0;
    returnResult.IntegerResult = 0;
    size_t counter = 0;  // should use `size_t` here

    char sign = inputString[0];
    if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') { // Look for + sign too
        counter++;
    }

    while (inputString[counter] != '\0') {
        int digit = inputString[counter++];
        if (digit < CONVERT_ZERO || digit > CONVERT_NINE)
        {
            returnResult.ErrorStatus = -1; // invalid input
            return returnResult;
        }

        digit -= CONVERT_ZERO;

        // Test if overflow is about to occur...

        if ((returnResult.IntegerResult <= INT_MIN / 10) &&
                ((returnResult.IntegerResult < INT_MIN / 10) || (-digit < INT_MIN % 10)))
        {
            returnResult.IntegerResult = INT_MIN;
            returnResult.ErrorStatus = 2; // detected overflow
            return returnResult;
        }

        returnResult.IntegerResult = returnResult.IntegerResult * 10 - digit;  // note use of -
    }

    if (sign != '-') {
        if (returnResult.IntegerResult < -INT_MAX)
        {
            returnResult.IntegerResult = INT_MAX;
            returnResult.ErrorStatus = 2; //overflow detected
            return returnResult;
        } else {
            returnResult.IntegerResult = -returnResult.IntegerResult;
        }
    }

    return returnResult;
}

void FromUnsignedIntegerToString(unsigned int inputUnsignedInt, char buffer[])
{
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%u", inputUnsignedInt);
}

void FromIntegerToString(char buffer[], int integer)
{
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", integer);
}
```

I've decided to remove all checking with the `From*ToString` methods and just encapsulate `snprintf` into a method.

Comment: @admin why did you edit out my "thank you to all who contributed?"