# K&R atoi() variation

Tags: beginner, c, array, parsing, integer

I'm currently learning C with *The C Programming Language* by K&R and this is my current exercise:

> Rewrite appropriate programs from earlier chapters and exercises with pointers instead of array indexing. Good possibilities include `getline`, `atoi`, `itoa`, `reverse`, `strindex` and `getop`.

This is my `atoi` solution with pointers:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int atoi(const char *nptr)
{
    while(isspace(*nptr++)) // skip white space
        ;

    long long val = 0;
    const char *start = nptr;

    if(*nptr == '-' || *nptr == '+')
        nptr++;

    while(*nptr >= '0' && *nptr <= '9')
        val = val*10 + *nptr++ - '0';

    return (*start == '-') ? -val : val;
}
```

I'm currently a little bit unhappy with the idea, that my code can't do anything against values smaller than `INT_MIN` and values greater than `INT_MAX`, but I can't come up with a solution that fits my expectations of good code.

- I could just return `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, but then the caller can't decide between the actual values and an error in form of `INT_MIN`/`INT_MAX`.
- It is also possible to use a second argument - a pointer to an `int`. The function will write the value into this `int` and will return 1 if it was successful and 0 if it wasn't.

I want to hear your thoughts on how I should handle this special case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bug right on the first statement:

> ```
> while(isspace(*nptr++)) // skip white space
>     ;
> ```

I didn't vote to close your post as off-topic for broken code to make a point:
it might seem cool to do two things at once in a loop condition (condition + increment),
it's not recommended, for two reasons:

- It's best to have one statement per line

  - A `for (;;)` is an exception, where it's allowed
- The loop condition should be about the condition. Leave it at that, move the incrementing logic inside the loop body in a `while` loop.

The bug is an off-by-one error: when the first digit is found,
the condition is false, but the pointer will be still incremented,
moving past the first digit. As a result, a string like "123" gets parsed as 23.

The fix is simple, and follows the above recommendations about writing loops:

```
// skip white space
while (isspace(*nptr)) {
    nptr++;
}
```

---

> I'm currently a little bit unhappy with the idea, that my code can't do anything against values smaller than INT_MIN and values greater than INT_MAX, but I can't come up with a solution that fits my expectations of good code.

Hm, the method is declared to return an `int`...
So it seems you don't like that `int` is limited within `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` by the language. There's just one thing to do: change the return type to something bigger, like a `long`!

---

Finally, when comparing against a variable to multiple files in the same conditional expression, often it's more readable to put the conditions in numerical increasing order, for example instead of this:

> ```
> while(*nptr >= '0' && *nptr <= '9')
> ```

Write like this:

```
while('0' <= *nptr && *nptr <= '9')
```

Comment: Thank you really much for the answer! I really appreciate all the help I can get. Probably I was a little too rash with the _while_ loop and the increase of the pointer. It also makes way more sense to write `while('0' <= *nptr && *nptr <= '9')`

Answer (score 2):

1. Code fails to handle `INT_MIN` correctly in the rare case when `int` and `long long` have the same range.  But there is *no* need for `long long`.

   Using only `int`, assume `INT_MIN == -2147483648`, `INT_MAX == 2147483647` and input is `"-2147483648"`.  `val` will attempt to take on the value of `2147483648` and overflow before the final negation.  `int` overflow is undefined behavior.  An easy [solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64049/29485) involves accumulating the negative sum rather than the positive one.  That solution also shows overflow prevention/detection without resorting to a wider signed integer type..
2. Other have pointed our the `while(isspace(...` issue.  There is more.  `char` may be signed and `isspace()` is only valid over the `unsigned char/EOF` range.  Better to do:

   ```
   while(isspace((unsigned char) *nptr)) {
     nptr++;
   }
   ```
3. Best not to re-use the name of a C standard  function:

   ```
    int LSTL_atoi(const char *nptr);
   ```
4. Suggest a function signature that returns an `int` and some measure of success.

   ```
    int LSTL_atoi(const char *nptr, bool *success);
   ```

---

> ...thoughts on how I should handle this special case.

String to `int` could return a value (function return) and code (address of code passed) to indicate various issues.

```
int my_atoi(const char *s, enum convert_T *code);

Code           Value
0              INT_MIN ... INT_MAX
Overflow       INT_MIN or INT_MAX
No digits      0
Trailing text  0
```

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive Are you seeking additional review of the code?